# How to get the Slave commit timestamp using MySql replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication, mysql-8.0

I've been looking for ways to collect information about the replication delays on MySql 8. I found an alternative solution, but I imagine there's a more straightforward way to do that.

By reading its [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/), I found out that I could get useful information in the performance_schema database.
When I look into the table *replication_connection_status* on the Slave server I can find the following information, among others:

- When the original Master commited the transaction (*LAST_QUEUED_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP*)
- When the immediate Master commited the transaction (*LAST_QUEUED_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP*).
- When the Slave started and finished to write the updates in its relay log (*LAST_QUEUED_TRANSACTION_START_QUEUE_TIMESTAMP*, *LAST_QUEUED_TRANSACTION_END_QUEUE_TIMESTAMP*).

But it lacks the information about when the transaction was commited on this Slave server.

**The alternative solution:**
Perform replication of these updates, from the Slave server to a third server (its master would be the Slave we're trying to get this info from), and then looking the column *LAST_QUEUED_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP* on the third server, which would be when the main Slave server has commited the transaction.

**A possible solution:**
The table *events_transactions_history* may contain the time where the transaction ended, but the time format is confusing.
According to [2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-timing.html):

> The timer baseline (“time zero”) occurs at Performance Schema
>   initialization during server startup. TIMER_START and TIMER_END values
>   in events represent picoseconds since the baseline. TIMER_WAIT values
>   are durations in picoseconds.

I have no idea of how to know what this "time zero" would be exactly, all we're given is that it occurs during server startup, but how could I get this exact time?

And of course, if there's an easier solution that I've missed, let me know.

Thanks.